# Can I pipe C# output to PHP?

Tags: c#, php, connection

I'm looking for a way to use my C# program in my .php page. I can imagine 2 ways:

1. running the c# .exe in the server, and reading the output in .php file.
2. running c# .exe directly on server.

And I don't know if either is possible. And if so, how ?

p.s.: Currently I'm working with a C# class that produces suffices for Turkish words, called [TurkceEkler](https://code.google.com/p/turkceekler/).
And what I want to do is use this to produce suffices for usernames of my website (MySQL) database, and somehow pipe it to my php scripts.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 5):

If you can run your c# app as a command line utility, you can call it using the exec function

```
Exec('myturkishapp.exe -f myfile', $output)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example, it looks like the c# app is only a couple hundred lines of source code, I'd probably recommend straight up conversion to PHP since nothing else will give you the same performance. The general approach, however, (if you want this to scale) is to have a server run the c# app and return the result. You can look into mod_mono which can run this natively on Apache if you don't have a Windows server handy:

http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

Comment: Thanks! Yes, converting to php would be ideal, but (as you said) I wanted to learn if I could run my C# files in web server. I also dream of "publishing" C# files on websites. I mean, visually, with buttons etc. In a way similar to that Unity does with Unity Web Player. I hope there is already such a plug-in that I haven't heard of. Thanks to both answers !